# C check if space exists in array, if not reallocate more space?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory, malloc

I have to write a program which takes a string argument such as "abcd" and returns a new string like "a-bb-ccc-dddd". so for each char in the string, increment its repetition in new string.

In something like C# or Java I would just use a StringBuilder but in C I'm not sure how to check if the string has enough space for a new character. if not, reallocate.

```
       char *str = malloc(strlen(source) * sizeof(char));
       for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(source) - 1; i++)
               (for int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
                 if (space_exists_in_string(source))
                     str[j] = source[i]; 
                 else {
                    str = realloc(str, strlen(str) * 2);
                    str[j] = source[i]
                 }
```

So basically im looking to find a way to check if (space_exists_in_string).

Thanks

Comment: You have to keep track yourself with a variable. Ex: `size_t bytes = strlen(source); str = malloc (bytes);`. And later: `bytes *= 2; str = realloc(str, bytes);`

Comment: Why don't you pre-allocate the full size of the final string? From your example it seems you can compute that as the sums of the first `n` numbers (where `n` is the length of the string) that equals to `n * (n + 1) / 2`, plus the number of '-'s, that is `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is declared as character array, like `char arr[]`, you can call `sizeof(arr)` and you'll get the size of the array. But, if it is allocated some heap memory using malloc or calloc, you cannot get the size of the array, except for calling `strlen()`, which only gives the size of the string, not the memory location. So, either declare your string as an array of characters or store the size of the memory created (when created dynamically) and update it every time you extend/shrink your memory.

In your case, I think it would be simple if you allocate some storage for your output and iterate through input and insert data into output. This way, you know how much data to allocate to output and you don't need to extend it. Required space for your output would be `(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 +... strlen(input) times) + (strlen(input)-1)`

Comment: i.e., sum of first strlen(input) natural numbers       +    (strlen(input) - 1) for '-'.